# sonarLint: make this anonymous inner class a lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, anonymous-function, sonarlint

Below code has a notification from SonarLint:

```
handler.setFileNameGenerator((new FileNameGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String generateFileName(Message<?> message) {
        if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
            return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
        }
    }
}));
```

I was trying the below but having issues with the `throw new IllegalArgumentException` piece:

```
handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> 
       (message.getPayload() instanceof File) ? 
       ((File) message.getPayload()).getName() : 
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload."));
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a conditional expression: you can't have a `throw` statement as part of it. That's the first problem.

The second challenge is that you need to raise an exception, so your current expression using a conditional expression won't work, unless you use a block:

```
handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> {
    if (message.getPayload() instanceof File) {
        return ((File) message.getPayload()).getName();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.");
    }
});
```

Which looks more like a copy/paste of your anonymous class...

Alternatively, you can use a Optional to clean it up:

```
handler.setFileNameGenerator(message -> Optional.of(message.getPayload())
        .filter(p -> p instanceof File)
        .map(f -> (File) f)
        .map(File::getName)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("File expected as payload.")));
```

Comment: Your second code snippet lacks the `getName()` call.

Comment: you can just modify the first map with: `.map(f -> ((File) f).getName())` and get rid of the second map